# Could not find any META-INF / No Persistence provider

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named market
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at util.Manager.<init>(Manager.java:19)
    at util.Manager.getInstance(Manager.java:14)
    at dao.PadraoDAO.listarTodos(PadraoDAO.java:11)
    at view.eeee.main(eeee.java:33)
```

I have these errors when trying to compile:
my hibernate 5.4.3.Final
I created my META-INF folder

[image]

how can i solve this?

Comment: Check if your have `META-INF/persistence.xml` in the build destination folder.

Comment: I try to create inside the src folder, but eclipse won't let

Comment: which build tool are you using? maven, gradle...?